# Roles.AddUsersToRoles() requires IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: c#, sql, model-view-controller, simplemembership, user-roles

Migrated from LocalDB to SQL Server. 
Trying to add role to user:

```
if (!Roles.GetRolesForUser("admin").Contains("Admin"))
                Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new[] { "admin" }, new[] { "Admin" });
```

and catching this:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table
>   'webpages_UsersInRoles' can only be specified when a column list is
>   used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is simple: check your `webpages_UsersInRoles` fields. **Identity Specification on all fields MUST BE disabled**.